# php iterate through array of objects inside an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

I am trying to loop through all posts in my database and grab their id. Here is what I have so far:

```
$posts = $db->select("posts","*",array());

foreach ($posts as $value) {
    $response['postvalue'] = $value;
}
```

When I run the code above I get this in my console.

[image]

inside those objects I have a property 'id'.

When I run this:

```
$posts = $db->select("posts","*",array());

foreach ($posts as $value) {
    $response['postvalue'] = $value->id;
}
```

I get a null value:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Is the id actually called `id` Selecting `*` does not help us much

Comment: Also in a loop you need to use `$response['postvalue'][] = $value->id;` or you are over writing the `$response['postvalue']` in each iteration round the loop

Comment: Yes the id is called id

Comment: So does `$db->select("posts","*",array());` return the rows as objects or arrays i.e. is it `$value->id;` or `$value['id'];`

Comment: As guessing games go this is quite fun, but a bit more detail in the question would be useful. Remember `$db->select()` is not vanilla code for any of the standard PHP MYSQL API's

Comment: it returns them aa an array of objects

Comment: yes sorry, I am using SLIM that is why you see this $db->select()

Comment: Then simply add `$posts = $db->select("posts","*",array()); print_r($posts);` to see what is actually being returned by the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125251/discussion-between-jason-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: I am updating the question to show you what my console spits out for the $posts

Comment: not having a good day and my mind is in a rut. If you want to help great but please don't bash me for my error

Comment: Well at least expand one of `0: Object` so we can see whats in there

Comment: it has a lot of properties. you don't need those. all you need to know is one of those properties is titled "id"

Comment: try echo var_dump($value) inside for loop

Comment: I dont see how either of the snippets you show can produce and array of anything. Please check that the code you show us is the code you are actually running _we are not clairvoyant and we are not looking over your shoulder_

Comment: `$response['postvalue'] = $value->id;` will not produce an array it will overwrite `$response['postvalue']` each time round the loop leaving you with only the LAST `id` in a variable called `$response['postvalue']`

Comment: So whatever the array you are looking at it is not the one generated by this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to add a var dump and post the data structure of the posts array. Currently it would be anyones best / lucky guess without knowing how that data looks..  this way people will be able to help you

```
$posts = $db->select("posts","*",array());
//var_dump($posts); 
foreach ($posts->data as $value) {
    $response['postvalue'][] = $value['id'];
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't. I am running an Angular app using php SLIM for the RESTful APi. I am running, openlog("myScriptLog", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL0); and when I run this syslog(LOG_WARNING, "JASON HI = " . print_r($posts)); I get a 1

Comment: I can run this $response['posts'] = $posts; before the foreach loop which is what you see in the updated image above

Comment: Run `syslog(LOG_WARNING, "JASON HI = " . print_r($posts,TRUE));` That returns the result rather than writing it direct to the browser

Comment: (add true to the second param to return )  print_r($posts, true)

Comment: here is part of one of them. Array#012(#012    [status] => success#012    [message] => Data selected from database#012    [data] => Array#012        (#012            [0] => Array#012                (#012                    [id] => 1#012                    [guid] => ...

Comment: this? $response['postvalue'][] = $value->id; it gave out null values

Comment: yes beacuse after you posted - it was clear that it should be accessed by $value['id']

Comment: So here is why I am so frustrated. I had tried $value['id'] earlier. when I use $value['id'] I get an Application error. the message says: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: I think I am going to try a different approach, thx for you help. Even though this did not solve my issue I wanted to give you props for helping

Comment: It looked to me like you need to use value['id'] - but also you should have adjusted the for each loop to loop through $posts->data instead of just $posts